# Python - how to convert parent child into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have a parent child dict that looks like this where the key is child and 0 is root node.

```
node[0]=[{"parms":{"meta1":"foo"},"name":"RootNoe"}]
node[1]=[{"parent":0,"data":{"parms":{"meta2":"bar"},"name":"country"} }]
node[2]=[{"parent":1,"data":{"parms":{"meta3":"baz"},"name":"day"} }]
```

I need to create a nested json object that looks like this:

```
test = {
        "params": {"parms":{"meta1":"foo"},
        "name": "RootNode", 
         "children": [ 
                     {
                     "parms":{"meta2":"bar"},
                      "name":"country",
                      "children": [
                                 {"parms":{"meta3":"baz"},
                                  "name":"day","children": []}
                                 ]
            }]  
        }
```

How do I do that in python?

Comment: `{{"parms":{"meta1":"foo"},"name":"RootNoe"}}` - this is not a python dictionary.

Comment: @eumiro: It could have been a set with one element, but `dict`s are not hashable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could construct the tree from the definition you have in a loop.

```
for element in node:
    if 'parent' in element:
        if 'children' not in node[element['parent']]:
            node[element['parent']]['children'] = []
        node[element['parent']]['children'].append(element)
        del element['parent']

test = node[0]
```

`children` needs to be present for this to work, but I'm hoping you get the gist.
Also note that this modifies the `node` sequence.

Comment: What do you mean children needs to be present?  I tried and it did nit give me the test dict.  I replace if 'parent' in node[element] else did not work.

Comment: You use a `'children': <value>` in your output `test`. `...['children']` will cause an error if you hadn't inserted it first. I've update my answer to deal with that, though there are similar solutions that could be considered 'prettier' :)

Comment: Is tnat pseodocode?  I cant get your code to work as is.  How should transform the node hash to make it easier?  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/tree_json.py", line 64, in <module>
    if 'parent' in element:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: It's valid Python code, though it might need some work to run without errors in your script. It mostly shows the use of `parent` as the index of the 'node' to which to add the children. Turning this approach into working code shouldn't be too hard.